# Creating an issue with JIRA API `Anonymous users do not have permission to create issues in this project. Please try logging in first.`

Tags: jira

I have a simple request that I am sending to a JIRA server

```
curl \
   -D- \
   -u 'api_key_label:api_key' \
   -X POST \
   --data '{"fields": {"project":{"key": "my_proj"}, "issuetype": {"name": "Bug"}}}' \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   https://my_instance/rest/api/2/issue/
```

When I send the request I get the response

```
{"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"project":"Anonymous users do not have permission to create issues in this project. Please try logging in first."}}%
```

If anyone has any experience with this I would appreciate some advice. Is the -u parameter supposed to base64 encoded?

Comment: The user given with an api token shouldn't be the label you gave the token, but the email address of the user who created it. See https://support.atlassian.com/atlassian-account/docs/manage-api-tokens-for-your-atlassian-account/

Answer (score 0):

Python

```
        import requests
        from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
        import json

        data = json.dumps({"fields": {"project":{"key": "VER"},"summary": "summary": {"name": "Bug"}}})
        
        url = 'https://my_instance:8080/rest/api/2/issue/'
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        response = requests.post(url,auth=('email_accoount','api_key'),data=data,headers=headers)
```